# How to run bash command during redirect << EOF

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, eof, io-redirection

I know there's some way to run bash command during redirect, but I don't know how exactly it is done.

I want to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -uUser -pPasswd << EOF
echo 'I wanna echo something by using echo which is run by bash'
use Mydb
some sql commands here
commit;
EOF
```

I had ever done that by mistake by using " in the "<< EOF" , but failed to make it now.

Comment: That is the correct syntax, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It seems more likely that you are missing some `;` in your MySQL command.

Comment: @merlin2011 since quotes might be confusing, I'll use system command, it's so clear.  Sorry for missing the ';' , I just post too hurry.

Comment: @ruakh sorry for my bad English. I want to run echo(bash) command besides(is this the correct word) a lot of mysql commands, to show the process of mysql commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`system` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html) from within the `mysql` command line client:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -uUser -pPasswd << EOF
system echo 'I wanna echo something by using echo which is run by bash';
use Mydb
some sql commands here
commit;
EOF
```

Comment: @Blangero: Is `system` command not working for you for some reason?

Comment: No, it works fine, why did you ask? Did I do something wrong or confusing? @anubhava

Comment: No worries I was just checking if I found some glitch with this command.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using a heredoc to interact with MySQL from bash, you can simply call mysql itself in batch mode. This is useful when you have reasonably short queries and will eliminate needing to call system from within the heredoc body. The general form in bash is:

```
$(mysql -uuser -hhost database.table -Bse "any valid mysql command")
```

(you may omit `.table` if it is identified in your query) To handle the information returned by mysql, it is usually advisable to return the information to an array:

```
results=( $(mysql -uuser -hhost database.table -Bse "any valid mysql command") )
```

In that regard, you can structure your scripts in a more flexible manner.

Comment: It is very useful and I'll try it next time. Thank you very much!